# how to print keys and values in a fetched json of dictionary and lists?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am new to python and have some understanding of how to use lists and dictionaries, but what ever i do i cant seem to print out the json values i need when fetching from an API. What i Need is value of "value": 500000 and "_timestamp": "2020-12-08T11:04:06.150000+01:00"

The get request returns:

```
json_data = json.loads(response.text)
someObjects = json_data.get("_embedded").get("someObjects")
```

and this is the json value I get:

```
{
   "_links": {
     "self": {
     "href": "https://api-test.com/api-test/api/v1/object/?_limit=1"
 },
    "next": {
    "href": "https://api-test.des.com/api/api/v1/object/deal/? 
     _limit=1&_offset=1"
  }
},
  "_embedded": {
     "someObjects": [
      {
        "dealstatus": {
        "id": 15101,
        "key": "agreement",
        "text": "4. Agreement"
    },
    "value": 500000,
    "quotesent": "2016-08-25T00:00:00+02:00",
    "expecteddate": "2016-08-01T00:00:00+02:00",
    "closeddate": "2019-06-05T00:00:00+02:00",
    "person": 1052,
    "coworker": 1003,
    "wonlostreason": "",
    "company": 1002,
    "name": "Big business",
    "probability": 1,
    "weightedvalue": 500000,
    "todo2": null,
    "_id": 1001,
    "_timestamp": "2020-12-08T11:04:06.150000+01:00"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

Im am not sure if I am doin this correctly, but when I type e.g:

```
    for key, value in response.items():
        print(key, value)
```

I get error:

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your some_objects key value is actually a list. So you get the value like below

```
for item in someObjects:
   print(item['_timestamp'])
   print(item['value'])
```

In your code, you are actully trying to loop through the json document and not the dict